# When rails maintenance policy updates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

By seeing rails maintenance policy,
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/maintenance_policy.html

we can know, these versions are now supported for these security issues.

- Security Issues: 5.2.Z, 5.1.Z
- Severe Security Issues: 5.2.Z, 5.1.Z, 5.0.Z, 4.2.Z

But I'd like to know when rails community ends these supports.
Does anyone know the dates and the pointer to the dates?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.2 - March 1st, 2019

> "As per our maintenance policy, the release of Rails 5.1 will mean that bug fixes will only apply to 5.1.x, regular security issues to 5.1.x and 5.0.x, and severe security issues to 5.1.x, 5.0.x, and 4.2.x. This means 4.x and below will essentially be unsupported!" - [Rails 5.1.0.rc1 Release Notes](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2017/3/20/Rails-5-1-rc1/)

> "For major security issues, all releases in the current major series, and the last release in the additional major series will receive patches and new versions. This is currently 5.2.x, 5.1.x, 5.0.x and 4.2.x." - [Rails Security](https://rubyonrails.org/security/)

Rails doesn't seem to list official EOL dates.  From the above quote it looks as though the EOL of 4.2 will be on the realease of Rails 6.0.0.rc1.  That is currently slated for [March 1st](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2018/12/20/timeline-for-the-release-of-Rails-6-0/). The EOL schedule for Rails 5 versions can be determined in a similar way.